# why does bss segment contain initial 4 bytes when no uninitialised global or static variable is there in code

Tags: c, memory-management

I have this simple code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      return 0;
    }
```

running the size command on the executable show the following output

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1053     276       4    1333     535 a.out
```

My question is , even though i don't have any unintialised global or static variable, why does bss has 4 bytes?

Comment: Maybe something in `stdio.h` does so. Remove the include and then check the stats again.

Comment: Why are you focused on BSS? Why not ask "Why do I have 276 bytes of initialized data?" Or "Why does a single `ret` instruction take 1053 bytes?` They all have the same answer.

Comment: well , i have a vague idea.
It has to do with the initial procedure calls that are done.
May be _init and __libc_start_main, But i'm not sure!

Comment: Might not be the library functions; it's possible that the runtime itself could be using that memory.

Comment: I have checked removing stdio.h, Same output!

Comment: Try the `size -A` command. It might give you more interesting output.

Answer (score 8):

You link your code against the standard C library. Specifically, you link against code that runs before `main()` starts and again after `main()` returns.

That code has data and bss requirements.

If you want to avoid those requirements, you can try linking without the standard library:

```
$ gcc  -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs x.c
$ size a.out
  text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
   118        0       0     118      76 a.out
```

Of course, then you'll need to make other (significant!) changes to your program:

```
$ cat x.c 
void _start() {
  __asm("mov $1, %eax; mov %eax,%ebx; int $0x80");
}
```

References:

- http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options